# Certificate not served from GCP with a CNAME pointing to an external domain (Zendesk)

Tags: ssl, subdomain, gcp

GCP subdomain CNAME points to an external domain and has a self-managed certificate assigned to it on GCP Certificate Manager. When trying to access the subdomain it shows that there is no SSL and the certificate is new and not expired. The subdomain points to an external domain (Zendesk subdomain). Does this mean the issue is from Zendesk server / account?

Comment: CNAME is a DNS concept and TLS protects the connection. Adding a CNAME record does not configure the server, which includes its TLS configuration.

Comment: It points to an external domain(Zendesk subdomain), does this mean the issue is from Zendesk server/account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zendesk server is not automatically aware that it should be serving anything on the hostname. Neither does it have a TLS certificate for it. You haven't fully followed the instructions on "[Host mapping - Changing the URL of your help center](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408838571930-Host-mapping-Changing-the-URL-of-your-help-center)".

> By default, the address of your help center is a Zendesk subdomain, such as "mycompany" in mycompany.zendesk.com. However, you can map a subdomain of your own domain (such as support.mycompany.com) to your default Zendesk address. This feature is called host mapping (see [About host mapping](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408838571930-Host-mapping-Changing-the-URL-of-your-help-center#topic_qqd_ccc_fsb)).
>
> The workflow for changing the address consists of the following steps:
>
> 1. [Getting a domain name and subdomain (if you don't already have one)](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408838571930-Host-mapping-Changing-the-URL-of-your-help-center#topic_n1l_3pk_j4b)
> 2. [Making the subdomain an alias of your default address](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408838571930-Host-mapping-Changing-the-URL-of-your-help-center#topic_kbc_npk_j4b)
> 3. [Specifying the new address](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408838571930-Host-mapping-Changing-the-URL-of-your-help-center#topic_bbf_xpk_j4b)
> 4. [Setting up a hosted SSL](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408838571930-Host-mapping-Changing-the-URL-of-your-help-center#topic_dyr_bqk_j4b)

Seems you have done steps 1 & 2 but skipped 3 & 4.